# java wordpress code confusion banner nativeads

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```html
<div id="SC_TBlock_670089" class="SC_TBlock">loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (sc_adv_out = window.sc_adv_out || []).push({
        id : "670089",
        domain : "n.ads1-adnow.com"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//st-n.ads1-adnow.com/js/a.js"></script>
```

can you help me to resize a banner 250x250

Comment: Firstly, this is unrelated to java. Secondly, your snippet doesn't run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help with neither a self-attempt nor a minimal example of desired behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Easy.

- Go on your website
- The adnow code runs and display the banner you want to resize
- Right click, inspect and find the node of the banner
- Find an ID, a class, whatever you can use in CSS
- In your CSS, for this selector, specify width and height

Usually those kind of ad provider have documentation, configuration, etc
Take a look